# Find digits $x, y$, and $z$ such that $2x5yz$ is greater than $28000$, is divisible by $8$, and has a remainder of $4 \mod 9$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As $x$ can only be either $8$ or $9$, I did:

For $x = 8$:
$$4*5+2*y+z \equiv 20+2y+z \equiv 0\pmod8 \\
2+8+5+y+z-4 \equiv 11+y+z \equiv 0\pmod 9$$

I'm unsure what to do next. Help?

Comment: You may plugin $z = -2y-20+8k$ in second congruence and solve $y$

Comment: do $x, y, $ and $z$ represent digits here? If so, then your equations should look more like: $20000 + x\cdot 1000 + 500 + y\cdot 10 + z$

Comment: @DavidDiaz Yes.

Comment: I see, you already reduced the modular equivalences. You could deduce what candidate numbers are both divisible by 8 and equivalent to $4\pmod 9$. Perhaps you can work in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$. Seems like there are multiple answers.

Answer (score 1):

Every number is congruent to its sum modulo $9$, so we want $8\mid5yz$ and $x+y+z\equiv6\pmod9$, $x<8$. So, the necessary and sufficient conditions are

- $x=8$ or $x=9$
- $4\mid yz$ but $8\not\mid yz$
- $x+y+z\equiv6\pmod9$

There are a lot of solutions to this system, such as $x=8$, $y=5$, $z=2$.